# How to convert integer starts with 0 to string in php?

Tags: php, decimal, octal

When I type an integer with a 0 in front in php, this integer will treated as an octal base number and converted automatically to decimal based number.

for example, when i declare a variable as follow:

```
$var1 = 01002992456;
echo "$var1";
```

the result will be 514

any one has an idea that i can keep that variable as it declared (as string)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah.. keep that variable as a string

Comment: If you begin an integer definition with a leading zero, it will be treated as an [octal value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), and this is an invalid octal value

Comment: Can't you just declare it as a string?

Comment: (FYI: Since you have you have an invalid octal number php only will take this as number: `01002`)

Comment: Don't give integers a leading 0 (unless you really use octal).... add leading zeroes using [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) only when you echo

Comment: If you want to display a value as octal, you can use sprint() with a mask of `'%o'`

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the number in quotes to keep it as string.

```
$var1 = '01002992456';
echo "$var1";
```

Output: 01002992456